# Cannot use Wifi Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, wireless, asus

I am dual booting Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 10 off two septate drives.
I have an ASUS K501UW-AB78 (which has no Wi-Fi switch). 
I am currently unable to access Wi-Fi while in Ubuntu, I am having no issues in Windows.

I ran `rfkill list` and got back:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

So my wifi is completely grayed out, I checked BIOS and wouldn't even know where to begin to turn off this hard block (or if it's even the real issue).

edit: 
was asked to run: 
grep [[:alnum:]] /sys/module/asus-nb-wmi/parameters/*
results: 
grep: /sys/module/asus-nb-wmi/parameters/*: No such file or directory

p.s. 
I have checked the website and tried all posted solutions before asking this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a BIOS problem, not an Ubuntu problem as there is no hardware switch.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `grep [[:alnum:]] /sys/module/asus-nb-wmi/parameters/*`

Comment: How is it a BIOS problem when it works fine in Windows but not in Ubuntu? Should I just get another Distro loaded at this point because for some reason 16.04 has trashy wifi drivers? Also will post the results of grep command here shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf <<< "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4"
```

then reboot and check BIOS if the Wi-Fi is enabled there.

Comment: I just figured this out as soon as you posted this, thanks for the response. It turned out to be a driver issue and not a BIOS issue after all. As soon as I got the drivers it worked. I appreciate the answer!

Comment: Which driver did you get? Please post an answer. My answer is not relevant in this case.